# Prove the set of all infinite binary sequences is uncountable by using Cantor's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cantor-set

This is different then the other versions of the questions here. I'm not supposed to use the diagonal argument. I'm looking to write a proof based on Cantor's theorem, and power sets.

Comment: Hint: $\{1,2,4,5,6,9\}\leftrightarrow(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,\dots)$

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is *not* different from *many* other versions of this question.

Answer (score 4):

dfsfjn already provided you with a hint, but in case it isn't obvious to you what she meant, let me leave you the following spoiler:

> For each $X \subseteq \mathbb N$ define $s_X \colon \mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ by $s_N(n) = 1$ iff $n \in X$. Let $^{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$ be the set of all functions $s \colon \mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$, i.e. the set of all infinite $0-1$ sequences. Define $\pi \colon \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to ^{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$ by $\pi(X) = s_X$ for all $X \subseteq \mathbb N$. Check that $\pi$ is a bijection and use Cantor's Theorem to conclude that $^{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$ is uncountable.

Comment: I am a she, not a he

Comment: @dfsfljn Sorry. I corrected that and will take this faux pas as a reminder to use gender neutral pronouns when and where I should.